# IPC versus UTS namespace

Tags: linux, networking, container

I am learning Kubernetes and it seems that they play crucial role in container implementations.They allow us isolation of global system resources between independent processes.Still I do not understand the whole picture.My pods

```
kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME          READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP          NODE
kubia-bzp4j   1/1       Running   0          17h       10.44.1.5   gke-kubia-default-pool-98519add-5kfr
kubia-hzd8b   1/1       Running   0          1h        10.44.0.7   gke-kubia-default-pool-98519add-hsrc
kubia-kgbtb   1/1       Running   0          1h        10.44.2.5   gke-kubia-default-pool-98519add-25c1
```

Kubernetes in Action says that

```
all containers of a pod run under the same IPC namespace
and can communicate through IPC
```

Does this imply that containers outside same pod can not communicat thgough IPC?
How they communicate?
Why do we need IPC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UTS namespaces contain just two identifiers: the system hostname and the (rarely used) NIS domain name.

IPC namespaces contain a specific kind of IPC objects known as "POSIX IPC" and "SysV IPC" – shared memory areas, message queues, and semaphores. They don't include TCP/IP nor Unix domain sockets nor other communication methods.

(TCP/IP is isolated by using *net* namespaces, although usually containers are deliberately given a virtual interface through which to reach the main network. Unix domain sockets are isolated by using *mount* namespaces, as they follow the same rules as file paths.)

See the [namespaces(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html) manual page for a longer explanation.